# SQL Server 2008 - Join 7 tables together

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have seven tables (which have unique rows, but some of the columns are the same, but most our unique to each table). I want to create one table/view of all seven tables, but display the columns with the same names in one.

**table1**

```
custid, ref#, uniq1, uniq2, field3, fiel4
```

**table2**

```
custid, ref#, uniq1, uniq2, field3, fiel4, field5, field6
```

**table 3**

```
custid, ref#, uniq1, uniq2, field5, field6, field7, field8
```

**Output required**

table/view

```
custid, ref#, uniq1, uniq2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8
```

There will be a lot of null values, but that is fine

Thanks

Comment: What happens if table1.uniq1, table2.uniq1 and table3.uniq1 all have values? Which should take precedence? Or would it be concatenation?

Comment: Tip: If you use `union` to combine rows from several tables you may find it handy, especially when debugging, to add a literal column to show the source of each row: `select CustId, RefNo, 'Table1' as [Source] from Table1 union all select CustId, RefNo, 'Table2' union all ...`

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that the `Union` predicate will force uniqueness across the results. Thus, you probably want to use `Union All` which will not "uniqueify" the results. In addition, you will need to add placeholder values (in this case, I used NULL) for the columns missing so that each Select statement returns the same number of columns:

```
Select custid, ref#, uniq1, uniq2, field3, fiel4, NULL As field5
    , NULL As field6, NULL As field7, NULL As field8
Union All
Select custid, ref#, uniq1, uniq2, field3, fiel4, field5, field6, NULL, NULL
Union All
Select custid, ref#, uniq1, uniq2, NULL, NULL, field5, field6, field7, field8
```

Lastly, in a Union or Union All query, the column name from the first query is what is used for the column names of the result. So, in the case of placeholder values in the first query, you will want to add column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You want a union, not a join:

```
select x, y from table1
union
select x, y from table2
...
```

Comment: but some of the tables have more columns than others, will the union still hold.

Comment: yeah, you need to have the same number of elements in the select, but you can just select null (or empty string / 0) where the table does't have the column: select custid, ref#, uniq1, null, uniq3... etc.